# Problems using Hibernate - JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, driver

I have a really strange issue when using hibernate to connect to a MySQLDB and add data.

This is the error I get:

> JDBC Driver class not found:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

This is how my hibernate.cfg.xml looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fpa-webapp</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I dont understand why I see a 500 Error when I navigate to the application; it says that the driver is not found.

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /fpa-webapp/.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
> Exception constructing service 'ValueEncoderSource': Error invoking
> ```
>
> service builder method
>   org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.buildValueEncoderSource(Map,
>   InvalidationEventHub) (at
>   TapestryModule.java:2287) (for service
>   'ValueEncoderSource'): Error invoking
>   service contribution method
>   org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateModule.contributeValueEncoderSource(MappedConfiguration,
>   boolean, HibernateSessionSource,
>   Session, TypeCoercer, PropertyAccess,
>   LoggerSource): Exception constructing
>   service 'HibernateSessionSource':
>   Error invoking service builder method
>   org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateCoreModule.buildHibernateSessionSource(Logger,
>   List, RegistryShutdownHub) (at
>   HibernateCoreModule.java:123) (for
>   service 'HibernateSessionSource'):
>   JDBC Driver class not found:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I'm sure the driver is in the class path.

What it could be?

Comment: *"Im sure the driver is in the class path."* How sure are you? :)

Comment: Is it a web-app or standalone, and how did you provide the classpath?

Comment: It is a web app. I am sure the driver is there because i opened the classpath file of the project and i saw the .xml tag there with the name of the driver.

Comment: I'll believe you if you run this code successfully from a ServletContextInitializer implementation: try { class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); System.out.println("you win") ; } catch (Throwable t) { System.out.println("you lied: "+t); }

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean by running from a servletcontextInitializer? Because with the current configuration i have(see above) i get an HTTP Error 500 and i cannot access the app. You mean to run it from somewhere else right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your driver is not on the classpath.

There are two ways to ensure it's on the classpath:

1. Add it to the global lib directory. For Tomcat this is `TOMCAT_HOME/lib`.
2. Include it in the war.

It depends on your requirements which you use.

If you're going to use Tomcat to manage the connection pool, you'll need to add it to the `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` and instead of defining your datasource directly in the hibernate configuration, you'll reference it via [jndi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

The only plausible explanation is that the `Driver` class is not on the CLASSPATH.

Check to make sure that the mysql-connector-java (or other relevant) jar is indeed in a place where it will get loaded. If you're 100% positive that it is, it might help to provide more information about how you know the class is being loaded, so that we can identify other possible causes.